# Why would Group policy drive mapping fail due to invalid path but manual mapping works fine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I set up a GPO  to map a few network drives amongst other things for some users.   The network drives fail to map on the clients but the rest of the policy works fine.  Looking at the event log it says the user 'Z:' preference item blah blah blah in group policy object did not apply because the network path was not found.   Trouble is, I know the path is correct  and I can go into FileExplorer and type in the path and map it manually. This works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you encounter the eventlog stating that there is an invalid network path?
Is it on the same machine where you can browse the path and the browsing and mapping error is done with same useraccount?
Can you share a screenshot of the settings in your drivemap just in case?

Comment: It was on the client side, I was going to snap some pictures for you but I realized I did something really dumb and had use the share name in the path while mapping the drive in GPO.   I was typing it in correctly on the client side so obviously that's why it would work. Thanks.    in a way you kind of solved my problem. How can I mark these as closed?  Is it worth leaving something like this here or should I just delete it?